# Integer value synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

I am new to multi-threading and getting some issues with the same kind of code.

I have the following code to lock based on an integer value.

```
Integer key = mmybatisMapper.getkeyByUserName(userName);  /// database call using mybatis to get key    
PostProcessingTask postProcessingTask = new PostProcessingTask(key,
                    userName);
Thread thread = new Thread(postProcessingTask);
thread.start();
```

//Post processing code

```
public class PostProcessingTask implements Runnable {

    private final Integer key;
    private final Integer name;

    private ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    public PostProcessingTask(final Integer key, final Integer name) {
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
        locks.put(key, key);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (locks.get(this.key)) {    
                    ///business logic
            }           
                
        }
    }   
}
```

The above code is working fine to achieve synchronization based on an Integer value.

However, now I'm again trying to achieve the synchronization in another project based on an Integer value and it's not working.
The only difference between the above code and the new project code is that the above code is getting Integer value from DB using MyBatis and my new code will be using Integer value from the REST endpoint request.

Can you please help me to solve the issue to do synchronization based on the value from REST endpoint request?

Comment: "it's not working" - what is not working? what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Also, post the code that is *not* working, rather than the code that is working, for debugging help.

Answer (score 2):

Doing `synchronized` on an `Integer` value is an extraordinarily bad idea, as `Integer.valueOf` has different behavior for integers outside [-128, 127], and completely unrelated bits of code might synchronize on it.  Synchronizing on an `Integer` value is likely to do unpredictably weird things.

There is a simple way of modifying your code to do what you're trying to do, though, and that is to use *just a completely meaningless `Object`* to synchronize on instead.  Write `locks.put(key, new Object())`, and keep the rest of your code the same.

Comment: No luck... I did changes at two places 
1-->private ConcurrentMap<Integer, Object > locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object >();
2--> locks.put(key, new Object());

Comment: @sagar: and what happened?  The resulting code is definitely _better_, but doesn't rule out other bugs.  For example, you probably want to share the `ConcurrentMap`, instead of having a different `ConcurrentMap` for each task, which always has only one entry.

Comment: yeah, code is better.....but synchronization is still not achieved using the mentioned changes...